# Does Interpol.MLApp.dll require a Matlab licence?

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to access Matlab functionality in C# using the Matlab Application Type Library.  My program compiles fine, but for the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Create the MATLAB instance 
    MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
}
```

I get this runtime error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {E9358F45-85A1-4291-B997-3D4F7E0C3FBF} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).'

I've registered it using regasm.exe, but that hasn't made a difference.  I've also downloaded Matlab Runtime.

Can I use Interpol.MLApp.dll without a Matlab licence?  Do I just need to register it in a different way?  Or is there a different library I should be using to execute Matlab code in C#?